# gfortran: module not found if used in a second module

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compile the following sample code with gfortran:

```
module a
use b
implicit none
save
real :: c = 2.5 
end module a

module b
use a
implicit none
save
real :: d = 1.5
end module b

program moduletest
use a
use b
implicit none
print*, c
print*, d
end program moduletest
```

Actually I do not understand the following message of error:
    moduletest.f90:2:6:

```
   use b
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘b.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Why can not I use module b in module a and vice versa? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't have such circular dependencies.  Now, you don't appear to need that here anyway, so how important is that aspect to your question?

Comment: Beyond the circular dependency, you will need to have compiled the module `b` before compiling module `a`.  That is what the message likely means.

Comment: Thanks, but with trying something like gfortran -c a.f90 I got the same error (sort of):   
            use b
                 1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘b.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory

Comment: This is precisely the point of circular dependency.

Answer (score 2):

A circular dependency of modules is not allowed. The standard states the following :

> **[11.2.2 The USE statement and use association](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)**
>
> The USE statement specifies use association. A USE statement is a
>   reference to the module it specifies. At the time a USE statement
>   is processed, the public portions of the specified module shall be
>   available. A module shall not reference itself, either directly or
>   indirectly.

According to your example, module `b` can only be build (become available) if module `a` is available. But module `a` can only be build, if module `b` is available. Hence module `a` references itself indirectly. ( `a` needs `b` which needs `a` which needs `b` which needs `a` which ... at infinitum)

It is important to realize that the `use` statement is by far not the same as including header files in other languages such as C or C++.